# Ocaml - Lazy.force

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Is my map function in:

```
type 'a stream = Cons of 'a * 'a stream Lazy.t

let rec ones = Cons(1, lazy(ones));;

let rec map (f:'a -> 'b) (s:'a stream) : 'b stream =
  match s with
  |Cons(h,t) -> Cons(f h, lazy (map f (Lazy.force t)));;
;;
```

Correct? Would Lazy.forcing it like that already make it memoized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

Note however that there will be no sharing of computation when applying it on a regular/cyclic instead of infinite datastructure (as `ones` here). Forcing the N first elements of `map succ ones` will still apply `succ` N times. (There is actually some research work on languages that would allow to detect such form of regularity/cycles and make strict mapping on them terminate, see e.g. the [CoCaml](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Projects/CoCaml/) project.)

Answer (score 5):

There's some magic in the ocaml Lazy type.  I think it's easier to understand lazyness when you implement it yourself, which is easy though not as syntactically convenient.  The tricks are

- delay evaluation using closures
- use ref cells to memoize computations

Here it's clear how and when the memoization happens during Lazy'.force.

```
module Lazy' : sig
  type 'a t
  val delay: (unit -> 'a) -> 'a t
  val force: 'a t -> 'a
end = struct
  type 'a susp =
  | NotYet of (unit -> 'a)
  | Done of 'a

  type 'a t = 'a susp ref

  let delay f = ref (NotYet f)

  let force f =
    match !f with
    | Done x -> x
    | NotYet f' ->
      let a = f'() in
      f := Done a;
      a
end
```

type 'a stream = Cons of 'a * 'a stream Lazy'.t;;

let ones =
  let rec ones' () = Cons(1, Lazy'.delay ones') in
  ones' ()
;;

let rec map f s = match s with
| Cons(h, t) -> Cons(f h, Lazy'.delay (fun () -> map f (Lazy'.force t)))
;;

Comment: What is the purpose of the second indirection at `type 'a t = unit -> 'a susp ref`? You are only ever returning `fun () -> r` or applying `    `let s = f () in`. Why can't you cut the middleman? PS: to be clear, I am asking why http://ideone.com/Eidm34 would not work.

Comment: Agreed.  It's unnecessary.  We should do type `'a t = 'a susp ref`.  The indirection is vestigial from an earlier attempt :)